# How do I slerp back and forth between quaternions for camera object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, quaternions

I don't understand why my camera doesn't slerp back. When I refresh the page, it slerps once. Then after that, it doesn't do anything if I move my mousewheel. I expect it to slerp back forward (as I scroll up and down) between the x quaternions.

```
export default class Experience {
    constructor(options = {}) {
    //...
        this.camera = new Camera();
        this.renderer = new Renderer(this.canvas);
        this.scrollTargetPosition = new THREE.Quaternion();
        this.scrollTargetPosition.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),0);


        this.onMouseScroll();
        this.animate();
    }

    onMouseScroll() {
        window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
            if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
                this.scrollTargetPosition.x = 0;
            } else {
                this.scrollTargetPosition.x = Math.PI / 2;
            }
        console.log("Target: " + this.scrollTargetPosition.x); //Pictures below
        console.log("Camera: " + this.camera.quaternion.x);
        });
    }

    animate() {
        this.camera.quaternion.slerp(this.scrollTargetPosition, 0.9);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

    }
}
```

Here's what the console.log's look like if I scroll up a bunch of times:
[image]

and if I scroll down:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you set the `Quaternion.x = Math.PI / 2`? Are you trying to rotate the camera by 90-degrees around the x-axis?

Comment: @Marquizzo yeah, but that's just a test. I want to eventually be able to change it to anything, not just 90 degrees around the x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you're treating [a Quaternion](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion) as if it were [Euler angles](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler), and they are hugely different.

Quaternion.x is *not* the x-axis rotation in radians. [Quaternions are made up of a 4-dimensional combination of imaginary and real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), so its `x, y, z, w` properties are better left alone. Instead, use the utility methods that performs the task you need. The method below sets the x-axis rotation to 0 or 90 degrees:

```
onMouseScroll() {
    let xAxis = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    window.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
        if (event.wheelDelta > 0) {
            this.scrollTargetPosition.setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, 0);
        } else {
            this.scrollTargetPosition.setFromAxisAngle(xAxis, Math.PI / 2);
        }
    });
}
```

After that, you should be able to perform your spherical interpolation as expected, however I recommend you replace the `0.9` with a smaller number like `0.1`, otherwise it'll pop into place too quickly:

```
this.camera.quaternion.slerp(this.scrollTargetPosition, 0.9);
```